# Android Geofencing API not executing my PendingIntent

Tags: android, google-api, android-geofence

I was trying to set up a geofence using the Google Geofencing API on Android. I created a BroadcastReceiver to handle the transition events and using an explicit intent I created a pending intent that I passed to the API when creating my geofence. However, the `onReceive` of my receiver never gets called. I've tried messing around with different settings for `setNotificationResponsiveness` and `setInitialTrigger` but nothing helps. I've tried it on a physical device (Nokia 7.1 with Android 10) and two emulators with Android 10 and 6 and it didn't work on either device. I tried waiting a few minutes for the event to get triggered but it never does. I've also tried different values for the radius, no result.
On Android 10, I can see in the system process log that the geofence does get registered but then I can only see some entries about location availability, such as this. Even when `isLocationAvailable` is true (and I don't know what that depends on), the receiver still doesn't get triggered:

```
I/GeofencerStateMachine: sendNewLocationAvailability: availability=LocationAvailability[isLocationAvailable: false]
```

This is a minimal code sample for which it doesn't work:
GeofenceReceiver.kt

```kotlin
class GeofenceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    companion object {
        fun makePendingIntent(context: Context) = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            1239,
            Intent(context, GeofenceReceiver::class.java),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.e("geofencereceiver", "received event")
        // some code
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml (irrelevant parts left out)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.patlejch.geofenceminimal">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <application ...>
        ....
        <receiver android:name=".GeofenceReceiver" />
        <!-- note that setting the receiver as exported makes no difference (and it shouldn't) -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Registering the geofence (`this` being an Activity). When this code gets executed, the app already has `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` granted:

```kotlin
// googleplex mountain view
val latitude = 37.421912
val longitude = -122.084068
val radius = 250.0f

val geofenceGms = Geofence.Builder()
    .setRequestId("test_geofence")
    .setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, radius)
    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
    //.setNotificationResponsiveness(...)
    .build()

val request = GeofencingRequest.Builder()
    //.setInitialTrigger(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
    .addGeofence(geofenceGms)
    .build()

val geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this)
try {
    geofencingClient.addGeofences(request, GeofenceReceiver.makePendingIntent(this))
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
} catch (e: SecurityException) {}
```

Has anyone had a similar issue that they successfully solved?

Comment: can you tell that, is your app is running in the background or app is closed??  and check if you gave all-time access location permission to your application.

Comment: @PJain the app was running in the foreground when i was testing it on the emulators. and yes, the app has all the necessary permissions.